# Why BeautifulSoup 4 returns none in console?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get(url="https://news.ycombinator.com/news")
yc_web_page = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(yc_web_page, "html.parser")
print(soup.title)
```

When i try to run this code i get this in my console.

```
None
```

Comment: I could not reproduce your error and got "<title>Hacker News</title>".

Comment: Perhaps you got a errant 4xx or 5xx error. Maybe add a check for `response.ok` as it also works for me.

Comment: yes response.ok did work for me as well thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `response.ok` and it worked. Here is the complete code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get(url="https://news.ycombinator.com/news")
response.ok
yc_web_page = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(yc_web_page, "html.parser")

print(soup.title)
```

and i get `<title>Hacker News</title>` in my console. So yeah it did work.